# adwords conversion code in google tag manager

Tags: google-ads-api, google-tag-manager

I have adword conversion code like this :

```
<!-- Google Code for XXXX Registration Form Conversion Page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = yyyyyyyyyyy;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "2";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var google_remarketing_only = false;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/yyyyyyyyyyy/?label=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
```

In Google Tag Manager, i have created a tag of AdWords Conversion Tracking type. I found only two textbox for conversion variables viz. Conversion ID and Conversion Label . There is no option for other variable like conversion format, conversion language, remarketing etc.

Where we need to configure these values in Tag Manager?

Comment: I use the conversion tag as it is and I don't have any problems with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Tag Manager only needs those values to pull the rest of the pixel information from the conversion goal that you set up in Google AdWords. The ID, label and value (optional) is all that is needed and then it does the rest of the work for you. Just make sure that you are firing the tag on the desired conversion page.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate a bit on cphill's correct answer, the rest of the parameters (except for `google_remarketing_only`, which is used for, well, remarketing tags) are only needed when you want to include a "Google Site Stats box" on your conversion page, which is supposed to help the converting user understand how Google tracked him:

[image: Google Site Stats box]

I have never seen such an info box on a live site, ever. Probably the developers of GTM haven't either, and that's why they didn't include it as an option in the Adwords Conversion Tag...

Comment: Ha ha. Seems like you agree with their reasoning of not including it as optional :)